# Detecting whether R expression will need graphical device

Tags: r

Having two general expressions ... (just example) ...

```
e1 <- expression({sin(x)})        # does not need gr. device
e2 <- expression({curve(sin(x))}) # needs gr. device
```

what would be the best way to detect that `e2` needs gr. device in advance before the `eval(e2)`.

Something like `detectNeedsGr(e2)`, returning `TRUE` and `detectNeedsGr(e1)`, returning `FALSE` and it should be able to work in non interactive mode.

So far I can imagine parsing `all.names(e2)` ..., rather inconveniently.

**More details**

1. every single expressions will be evaluated in the workflow
2. the nowledge of what expressions needs gr. output is needed **before** in the workflow to adjust workflow details, not after `eval` (it is obvious that after `eval` everyone knows)
3. expressions are not arbitrary, they come from well known definitions
4. it is possible to add into definition the logical option whether the particular expression will yield gr. output, but it is excessive and I want to avoid that and find out that programmatically.
5. I can design the workflow to use **after eval** logic, but it brings steps I would like to avoid and based on that I am specifying the question.
6. not a question of device capability etc.
7. the workflow will be incorporated in shiny app in this case, but generally it does not matter.

Comment: Best practice is to not evaluate arbitrary expressions.

Comment: @Rolland ... not an option

Comment: I hope my question is clear now.

Comment: "expressions are not arbitrary, they come from well known definitions" Then I would compile a list of plotting functions. You can always create the parse tree and look if functions such as `plot.xy` or `drawGrob` finally get called, but that's inefficient.

Comment: yes, that is the way which seams to me "childish" (sorry for the word) and I was hoping for some higher level based answers

Comment: Yes, that was me, with all respect to your effort, which is going astray of the question target and generally not useful in this matter.  I am sorry for that, there are some rules here and I believe I am just within mantinels.

Comment: You need to show a minimal reproducible example of what you are actually trying to do (within shiny). Possibly it would be possible to deal with your issue on the shiny side. I don't agree with your point 4. There is nothing excessive about keeping track. It's excessive to try and do this programmatically.

Comment: @Roland, I think I am clear. It is not question of `shiny` at all. It just happened that there my workflow is within shiny app. I am quite comfortable with shiny and even I am able to go around that. I am curious to find out in community if there is a way I do not know. I see now it is going totally astray. If you can, please close it.

Comment: I believe there isn't (and I believe this is pointless). Until an expression is evaluated, R doesn't know if a device is needed. You can crawl the parse tree and look for specific low-level plotting functions, but that would be really excessive.

Comment: @Roland, "I believe there isn't (and I believe this is pointless). Until an expression is evaluated, R doesn't know if a device is needed." ... so, would you like to provide this answer by standard way which could be voted by community?

Answer (score 1):

It might be easiest just to ensure that you always have a graphical device available:

```
grcap <- any(capabilities()[c("X11", "aqua")])
win <- .Platform$OS.type == "Windows"
inter <- interactive()
if(!(grcap || (win && inter)))
{
    filename <- paste0(tempfile(), "%03d.jpg")
    jpeg(filename)
}
```

This checks if your script is being run in a session with graphics capabilities. If not, any plots will be sent to jpg files in your temp directory, and deleted when you close R.

Comment: did you just downvote me for not using information you didn't put in your question?

Comment: Yes, that was me, with all respect to your effort, which is going astray of the question target and generally not useful in this matter.  I am sorry for that, there are some rules here and I believe I am just within mantinels.